# Drupal way of sending push notification to android devices

Tags: 7, services

I am trying to send push notifications to Android, and Apple iOS devices. To store the device tokens, I am using `cocoa rest client`. For iOS devices that is fine, but I didn't understand how to store `RegId` and token for the Android devices. as we have only 4 attributes, namely:

- token
- uid
- type
- timestamp

Generally, for Android we have to store RegId and device token, but in the table we don't have any attribute to store Regid. I am giving post values as `type=android,token=device token`.

Will this help me to send push messages to Android devices? Without RegId, I think it is not possible.

I am using the Push Notifications module.

Comment: The question should mention which module/library (if any) is used for iOS/Android push notification as it seems actually related to such module/librairy. Also, the question seems to be about the basic usage of the used module/library, and would probably be better handled in the module/library issues queue/tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Push Notifications](http://drupal.org/project/push_notifications) module. I've never done this -- but you're basically asking how do I send X message type to a user (SMS, Email, whatever). I've sent emails and SMS messages before ...

Beyond wanting to send this notification from within drupal/php ... there isn't anything really drupal specific in your question in terms of the drupal API.

If you dont userstand the protocol or APIs you want to talk to I would suggest you research them more as well. I would start by looking at the source code for the PushNotifications module and see how it handles the logic of what you are asking about ...

Comment: I am sorry for not mentioning this, i am using push notification module. with the help of this module i successfully sent notifications to ios devices. but i dint understand how for android.